# Draw text starting from point?

Tags: android

Since canvas.drawText(String text, float x, float y, Paint paint); draws this with the middle coordinates of x and y in the middle of it, is there a way to draw it starting from a point?

Comment: Default behavior of `paint` is to use `Align.LEFT`, not `Align.CENTER` as you describe. How are you calling the function in your code?

Comment: I had it set to Align.CENTER. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'll add an answer to help others who stumble here.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
canvas.drawText(text,x,y,paint);
```

([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextAlign%28android.graphics.Paint.Align%29))